# Arch Linux - get no ipv4 on vm's

Tags: arch-linux, windows, kvm, qemu

I have since some days a problem with my network connection on every vm. It doesn't matter whether Windows or Linux.

My host system based on Arch Linux with interfaces configured by systemd-networkd. Here are my config files for all interfaces.

**/etc/systemd/network/10-bo0.netdev**

```
[NetDev]
Name=bo0
Kind=bond

[Bond]
Mode=802.3ad
TransmitHashPolicy=layer3+4
MIIMonitorSec=1s
LACPTransmitRate=fast
```

**/etc/systemd/network/10-br0.netdev**

```
[NetDev]
Name=br0
Kind=bridge
```

**/etc/systemd/network/eno1.network**

```
[Match]
Name=eno1

[Network]
Bond=bo0
```

**/etc/systemd/network/enp14s0.network**

```
[Match]
Name=enp14s0

[Network]
Bond=bo0
```

**/etc/systemd/network/20-bo0.network**

```
[Match]
Name=bo0

[Network]
Bridge=br0
BindCarrier=eno1 enp14s0
```

**/etc/systemd/network/25-br0.network**

```
[Match]
Name=br0

[Network]
DHCP=yes
BindCarrier=bo0

[DHCP]
RouteMetric=10
```

My connection on the host system is established correctly.

```
markus@markus-pc:~$ ip a | awk '{ print "    " $0 }'
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp14s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master bo0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d6:58:88:05:c9:60 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master bo0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d6:58:88:05:c9:60 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f6:11:0f:03:bf:b1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.179.20/24 brd 192.168.179.255 scope global dynamic br0
       valid_lft 854751sec preferred_lft 854751sec
    inet6 2001:16b8:2efc:3900:f411:fff:fe03:bfb1/64 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 6755sec preferred_lft 3155sec
    inet6 fe80::f411:fff:fe03:bfb1/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: bo0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d6:58:88:05:c9:60 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::d458:88ff:fe05:c960/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:aa:68:d9:a1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: vnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master br0 state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:54:00:17:2b:75 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fe17:2b75/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I don't know if since the update from Arch Linux something has been changed on the default firewall settings or simply my vm's get no DHCP offers from my router.

How can I check if my virtual machine get a DHCP offer or something else so solve my IPv4 problem.

Some other informations:

- Linux Kernel: Linux 4.18.6-arch1-1-ARCH
- qemu 3.0.0

Answer (score 0):

So after some digging i found something.

First i did some systematical downgrading of most of the involved packages to see if there is something amiss there. So i did with libvirt, virt-manager, qemu, iptables, ebtables, dnsmasq but did not find anything of impact. Still no ip in a vm.

i usually use pacaur to compile the linux-vfio kernel out of the aur. After a recent SSD Failure i had no pacaur-cache left so downgrading to an older kernel (im at 4.18.9-vfio atm) was no option.
So i tried some of the mainstream kernels i had lying around in /var/cache/pacman/pkg. The recent 4.18.9 did nothing to improve the situation. But 4.16.8-1 did. Booting with it i get ip in the vms again.
In a few days i'm gonna sink some more time and pinpoint where the trouble is.

Gladly i don't need the VMs often.

edit: strangely enough the 4.14.71 lts kernel does not provide the ip address aswell. So there should be a somewhat recent patch that is at fault here.